# Error while upgrading SQL server 2012 to SQL 2017 : Failed to create a new folder 'X:\\xxxx'. The specified path is invalid

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Failed to create a new folder 'X:\MSSQL\DATA\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG'. The specified path is invalid (for example, it is on an unmapped drive).

I checked there is no X drive present in the server. I verified that all the default files for data and log points to the drives which are available in the server.

Not sure , how do I resolve this as i don't see X drive mentioned in any of the properties.

I have checked in Facets and database properties to verify the path.

Answer (score 2):

At the first sign of trouble during an in-place upgrade, fallback to a side-by-side upgrade.  Install a new instance of SQL 2017, preferably on a new VM, and migrate the databases, logins, jobs and settings from your old instance.